# pycharm in mac , command + click is not working

Tags: django, pycharm

I have pycharm 3.0. Recently ,  my ide started behaving weirdly , it was showing my imports as errors, but i never got any import error when i ran my `django` project. any way that was fixed , i gave relative path and the error highlighting vanished.

in this `moduleA.moduleB.moduleC` if i needed to go to moduleB, all i did this was command + click on the moduleA or moduleB and it used to take me to that place, now this suddenly stopped working, i don't remember changing any settings , but even if have changed , where do i reset it back? and what is this keyboard shortcut called?

Answer (score 0):

it could be possible that you don´t have selected a python interpreter for your project. Can you post your errors?

btw: [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) is on v3.4 now. Community Version is free. Pro you have to pay.